# how to insert n number of blank rows between existing rows alternatively

Tags: excel

Can anyone suggest me procedure or a formula to insert n blank rows in between a existing data?

for example:
I have data from A1 to A50, now I have insert n number of blank rows between each row.

input:

[image]

required output:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything so far that is not working?

Comment: Ya i have tried with a tutorial that exists in you tube but with that only one row can be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this screenshot:
[image]

In cell C3 enter the number of rows you want to insert between cells from column A. This cell has the range name "RowsToInsert". Alternatively, you can use `$C$3` in the formulas below

The formula in cell E2 is

```
=INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW(A1)/(RowsToInsert+1),1))
```

or type the first value manually. The formula in E3 is as follows, copied down:

```
=IF(CEILING(ROW(A2)/(RowsToInsert+1),1)=CEILING(ROW(A1)/(RowsToInsert+1),1),"",INDEX(A:A,CEILING(ROW(A2)/(RowsToInsert+1),1)))
```

When you change the value in cell C3, blank rows are added accordingly. Copy the formula down as far as required. Then copy column E and use Paste Special > Values to paste only the results.

Answer (score 1):

I would use VBA to achieve what you require and this is the code I would propose

```
Dim n As Long 'number of blanks
Dim dataLen As Long ' number of used rows
Dim currentRow As Long
Dim i, j As Long

dataLen = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
n = 3 'number of blanks
currentRow = 2 'start insert at row 2

For i = 1 To dataLen
    For j = 1 To n
    Sheet1.Rows(currentRow).Insert
    Next j

    currentRow = currentRow + n + 1 'offset the next row to start insertion 
Next i
```

Comment: can you suggest me either formula or some procedure instead of VBA?

Answer (score 0):

With formula It will be little complicated I guess.
Is this what you want?
=IF(ROW(B1)-(9*TRUNC(ROW(B1)/9,0))=1,"one",IF(ROW(B1)-(9*TRUNC(ROW(B1)/9,0))=4,"two",IF(ROW(B1)-(9*TRUNC(ROW(B1)/9,0))=7,"three","")))